# Kubuntu 20.04 Oxygen theme for GTK3

Tags: kde, gtk3, plasma-5, oxygen

I'm using Oxygen theme in KDE, GTK2 and GTK3 applications on 19.10. When I updated the system to 20.04 I can't find the Oxygen theme for GTK3 applications.
Is there any chance to take it back and how?

Comment: Is this the one?  https://store.kde.org/p/1162362/

Comment: No. It's only for Plasma 5.

Answer (score 0):

Although not perfect, not so long ago someone thankfully made this theme called Oxygen-SCSS. It isn't perfect but it does the job for me, since the oxygen-gtk3 project has been abandoned and is not compatible with more recent gtk3 releases.

https://www.pling.com/p/1394719/

In the gtk3 folder, you can edit the `_common.scss` file and recompile with the `parse-sass.sh` script if you want to change the color scheme.